# Array as value in json metadata properties send by Forge Derivative API

Tags: arrays, properties, metadata, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a question about the structure of metadata properties extract from a translated IFC model. In the JSON I get all the properties for all objects and sometimes the value for a property is an array.
For example in the picture, first line, the category of the object is not a string but an array.

I don't know if it's a bug or something wrong in the IFC but when I open it in IFC viewer, values are only strings, there is no array. The current IFC is the urban house model that I found on the Autodesk website and often used in the forge demo.

It's not a critical problem for me, I just check each time if the value is an array.
I just wanted to know.

Thanks

[Example of array in properties values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVUFR.jpg)

You can download IFC and Revit file

[Urban_House.ifc](http://www.mediafire.com/file/t4s7p1w7rf4ejra/Urban_House.ifc/file)

[Urban_House_2018.rvt](http://www.mediafire.com/file/bhc4p6btqz3eity/Urban_House_2018.rvt/file)

Comment: Could you consider providing a none-confidential reproducible IFC model to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com for investigating? I cannot reproduce this issue with mine. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my post, you can download ifc and revit file to test!

Comment: Thank you for the model. I'm checking with our engineering team and will get back to you A.S.A.P.

Comment: Please try to switch to the Revit based IFC translation pipeline. After switching, this issue cannot be reproduced anymore at my end. Here is the reference: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change

Comment: Ok, thank you I will try!